# Create pairs out of an array of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function that loops through some object properties.

It returns this:

Central Park: 0,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1

Juniper Valley Park: 2,0

Highland Park: 2,0,5,0

```
var parks = [
{
    name: 'Central Park',
    landmarks: [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1]]
},
{
    name: 'Juniper Valley Park',
    landmarks: [2,0]
},
{
    name: 'Highland Park',
    landmarks: [[2,0],[5,0]]
},]
function showLandmarks() {
 for (var i = 0, len = parks.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(parks[i].name +': '+parks[i].landmarks);
 }
}
showLandmarks();
```

I would like to create pairs out of the returned data. The expected result is:

Central Park: [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1]]

Juniper Valley Park: [2,0]

Highland Park: [[2,0],[5,0]]

I found a few topics here but only partial information.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want Juniper Valley Park to return [[2,0]]? You will make your parser on the other end simpler because it would always expect an array of zero or more pairs, rather than sometimes an array of arrays and sometimes an array of 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

instead of manipulating the results, You could `reduce` the original array to an object :

```js
var parks = [
  {
    name: "Central Park",
    landmarks: [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1]]
  },
  {
    name: "Juniper Valley Park",
    landmarks: [2, 0]
  },
  {
    name: "Highland Park",
    landmarks: [[2, 0], [5, 0]]
  }
];

const result = parks.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr.landmarks;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing `i` by one every loop, create a pair using `parks[i]` and `parks[i+1]` and add that pair to an accumulator array, then increment `i` by two.

You will just have to perform a check that `parks[i+1]` exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `+` between two objects it internally calls toString and changes than concate the converted string

```js
console.log([1,2]+[3,4])
```

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var parks = [{ name: 'Central Park',landmarks: [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1]]},{    name: 'Juniper Valley Park',landmarks: [2,0]},{ name: 'Highland Park',landmarks: [[2,0],[5,0]]},]

let obj = Object.fromEntries(parks.map(({
  name,
  landmarks
}) => [name, landmarks]))

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to manage through the Juniper entry since it isn't the same format, but the code below does the trick:

```js
var parks = [
  {
    name: 'Central Park',
    landmarks: [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1]]
  },
  {
    name: 'Juniper Valley Park',
    landmarks: [2,0]
  },
  {
    name: 'Highland Park',
    landmarks: [[2,0],[5,0]]
  }
];

function arrayToString(array) {
  return "[" + array.join(',') + "]";
}

function showLandmarks() {
  parks.forEach(function(park) {
    var landmarks = park.landmarks;
    if (!Array.isArray(landmarks[0])) {
      landmarks = [landmarks];
    }
    var row = landmarks.map(function(lm) {
      return arrayToString(lm);
    })
    var result = row.length > 1? "[" + row.join(",") + "]" : row.join(",");
    console.log(park.name + ':', result);
  })
}
showLandmarks();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a loop here you can use a forEach on the Array and not have to worry about the `i` index. This assumes for course that you always want the full array.

I suspect you actually want to have the `[]` printed around the coordinates.
if so you can use `map` to add them to each coordinate set.

I would say that even though Juniper Valley Park only has one entry, that entry should still be within an Array for its own to keep data consistent.

```
{
    name: "Juniper Valley Park",
    landmarks: [[2, 0]]
  },
```

This means we won't need any special logic to handle cases with only one coordinate.

```js
var parks = [
{
    name: 'Central Park',
    landmarks: [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1]]
},
{
    name: 'Juniper Valley Park',
    landmarks: [[2,0]]
},
{
    name: 'Highland Park',
    landmarks: [[2,0],[5,0]]
},]
function showLandmarks() {
 parks.forEach(park => 
    console.log(park.name +': ['+ park.landmarks.map(landmark => '[' + landmark +']') + ']'));
 }
showLandmarks();
```

Output:
Central Park: [0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1]]

Juniper Valley Park: [[2,0]]

Highland Park: [[2,0],[5,0]]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

remove JSON.stringify, if you don't need return a string instead of array of arrays.

```js
const landmarks = (...points) => {
  const result = [];
  while (points.length) {
    result.push(points.splice(0, 2));
  }
  return JSON.stringify(result);
};

// test
// Central Park:
console.log(landmarks(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1));
// Juniper Valley Park:
console.log(landmarks(2, 0));
// Highland Park:
console.log(landmarks(2, 0, 5, 0));
```